# Delphi image dimension

Tags: image, delphi

I have created a simple Opendialog, Edit1 with show message

I don't know why my function return:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(112): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'tagSIZE'
```

The complete code is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,Types, ExtDlgs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
//      procedure GetGIFSize(const sGIFFile: string; var wWidth, wHeight: Word);

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function GetGIFSize(const FileName: string): Windows.TSize;
type
  // GIF header record
  TGIFHeader = packed record
    Sig: array[0..5] of AnsiChar;     // signature bytes
    ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight: Word;  // logical screen width and height
    Flags: Byte;                      // various flags
    Background: Byte;                 // background colour index
    Aspect: Byte;                     // pixel aspect ratio
  end;
  // GIF image block header record
  TGIFImageBlock = packed record
    Left, Top: Word;      // image top left
    Width, Height: Word;  // image dimensions
    Flags: Byte;          // flags and local colour table size
  end;
const
  cSignature: PAnsiChar = 'GIF';  // gif image signature
  cImageSep = $2C;                // image separator byte
var
  FS: Classes.TFileStream;      // stream onto gif file
  Header: TGIFHeader;           // gif header record
  ImageBlock: TGIFImageBlock;   // gif image block record
  BytesRead: Integer;           // bytes read in a block read
  Offset: Integer;              // file offset to seek to
  B: Byte;                      // a byte read from gif file
  DimensionsFound: Boolean;     // flag true if gif dimensions have been read
begin
  Result.cx := 0;
  Result.cy := 0;
  if (FileName = '') or not SysUtils.FileExists(FileName) then
    Exit;
  FS := Classes.TFileStream.Create(
    FileName, SysUtils.fmOpenRead or SysUtils.fmShareDenyNone
  );
  try
    // Check signature
    BytesRead := FS.Read(Header, SizeOf(Header));
    if (BytesRead <> SizeOf(TGIFHeader)) or
      (SysUtils.StrLComp(cSignature, Header.Sig, 3) <> 0) then
      // Invalid file format
      Exit;
    // Skip colour map, if there is one
    if (Header.Flags and $80) > 0 then
    begin
      Offset := 3 * (1 shl ((Header.Flags and 7) + 1));
      if Offset >= FS.Size then
        Exit;
      FS.Seek(Offset, Classes.soFromBeginning);
    end;
    DimensionsFound := False;
    FillChar(ImageBlock, SizeOf(TGIFImageBlock), #0);
    // Step through blocks
    FS.Read(B, SizeOf(B));
    while (FS.Position < FS.Size) and (not DimensionsFound) do
    begin
      if B = cImageSep then
      begin
        // We have an image block: read dimensions from it
        BytesRead := FS.Read(ImageBlock, SizeOf(ImageBlock));
        if BytesRead <> SizeOf(TGIFImageBlock) then
          // Invalid image block encountered
          Exit;
        Result.cx := ImageBlock.Width;
        Result.cy := ImageBlock.Height;
        DimensionsFound := True;
      end;
      FS.Read(B, SizeOf(B));
    end;
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Size: Windows.TSize;
begin
    Size := GetGIFSize('file.gif');
    ShowMessage(Size);
  end;
end.
```

I use simply:

GetGIFSize(path/to/filename);

But Filename is a string, have you any idea why is not working?

Comment: You're trying to assign the `GetGIFSize` function result to a `string` type variable instead of `Windows.TSize`. That's the piece of code we're missing in your question.

Comment: Please post the **exact, entire compiler error you get**, along with which line it is happening with, and the **exact** code you're using to call the function. Saying "I use simply <somecodethatwontcompile>" isn't quite good enough (as @TLama has pointed out).

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite, i edited and i have added the code with error message

Comment: A word of advice: when you encounter a compiler error - select corresponding message and press F1, online help will appear with detailed explanation and even with friendly examples in the form on "produce" and "solve" code snippets.

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShowMessage` procedure takes as its only parameter `string` type value, but you were trying to pass there a `Windows.TSize` record. That's the reason, why compiler rejected compilation with such message. Moreover the `Windows.TSize` record type consists from 2 fields; from `cx` and `cy` where each is of numeric type, so except that you'd need to pass them *separately*, you'd need to convert their values to string before passing them into the `ShowMessage` procedure. That you can do in many ways, e.g. by:

***1. Using a Format function (preferred way)***

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Size: Windows.TSize;
begin
  Size := GetGIFSize('c:\File.gif');
  ShowMessage(Format('Width: %d; Height: %d', [Size.cx, Size.cy]));
end;
```

***2. Manual concatenation of the string (worse readable)***

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Size: Windows.TSize;
begin
  Size := GetGIFSize('c:\File.gif');
  ShowMessage('Width: ' + IntToStr(Size.cx) + '; Height: ' + IntToStr(Size.cy));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @TLama and all for good response. I use class Windows, and simple function, 2 solutions is good, but if i give a simple showmessage(Size); after Size := GetGIFSize('c:\File.gif'); error message [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(113): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'tagSIZE' why?

Comment: Wait, my answer is wrong according to your comment (update). Why did you accepted it ?

Comment: Sorry, because you helped me for know where is problem

Comment: Perfect now, i don't think that the error coming from showmessage. Very thank you, i understand now.. +100

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `TForm1.ButtonClick` event, with the `ShowMessage` call. `ShowMessage` takes a string parameter (the message to show), and you're passing it a `Windows.TSize` instead.

You need to convert the `TSize` record to a string in order to use it with `ShowMessage`. A `TSize` has two dimensions - width, represented by `TSize.cx`, and height, represented by `TSize.cy`, so you need to convert those dimensions to a displayable string representation:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Size: Windows.TSize;
const
  SizeDisplayMsg = 'Size - width (cx): %d height (cy): %d';
begin
    Size := GetGIFSize('file.gif');
    ShowMessage(Format(SizeDisplayMsg, [Size.cx, Size.cy]));
end;
```

Of course, if you're wanting to use the `TOpenFileDialog` to get the filename, you should use it instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Size: Windows.TSize;
const
  SizeDisplayMsg = 'Size - width (cx): %d height (cy): %d';
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute(Handle) then
  begin
    Size := GetGIFSize(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    ShowMessage(Format(SizeDisplayMsg, [Size.cx, Size.cy]));
  end;
end;
```